# Getting a warning when using special characters in paragraph element

Tags: html

I am working with HTML5 CSS3... I have to display a sentence which has special characters.But when I specify my sentence in paragraph element its giving me a warning...

### Below shown is my code snippet.

```
<p>Due to the related impact on the F&A proposal this action ....... (ex: controller's.....</p>
```

Its displaying me a warning triangle stating invalid character..Can anybody tell me how can avoid this warning...

I also tried using ""  and '' for the special characters , but its not removing the warning...

Comment: The warning is because HTML expecting something like `&Acute;` but its not complete. If you use `&amp;` instead of `&` the warning should go away

Comment: k .. i will try this out.. thanks for you response

Comment: yes its working... thanks again...:-)

Comment: I have added it as an answer so you can select it as one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The warning is because HTML expecting something like `&Acute;` but its not complete. If you use `&amp;` instead of `&` the warning should go away

Ao your code will end up being:

```
<p>
Due to the related impact on the F&amp;A proposal this action ....... 
(ex: controller's.....
</p>
```