# MatPaginator not working properly on deleting rows from MatTableDataSource

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have created a table with selection and pagination in angular 2 using angular material.

I have taken a button with the name **Remove Selected Rows** to delete the selected rows from the table.

But as a delete the selected rows , all the table data is being loaded which doesn't match with value specified for the pagination.

### Below is the stack-blitz link for my code..

https://stackblitz.com/edit/delete-rows-mat-table-vj4hbg?file=app%2Ftable-selection-example.html

### Below shown is the output.

Initially the table displays only the rows as specified for the pagination value.

[image]

But as I deleted the row 3 , all rows are being loaded even if the pagination value is only 3..

[image]

can anybody tell me how can I limit my table rows with the pagination value specified after deleting the rows.

Comment: I am not able to see your pagination in that demo snippet

Comment: i have updated ....now can you please see..

Comment: Still i am unable to see the `item per page` section

Comment: now its updated one...

Comment: did you get that...?

Comment: Yes...  wait and let you know

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166806/discussion-between-heena-and-ramesh-rajendran).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**[Here you go buddy.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/delete-rows-mat-table-odej4h?file=app/table-selection-example.ts)**

You forgot to reassign the paginator to the datasource after deletion. Angular may do some magic, but sometimes it needs a little bit of help.

I use a timeout because I always face an issue, feel free to try without it.

```
setTimeout(() => {
  this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
});
```

Comment: i didn't use timeout..can you tell whats the issue without timeout?

Comment: In my case, my paginator wasn't updated before being assigned to the datasource, so it was not updated (or in your case, it would be updated with a delay of one click). If it works for you without it, then great !

Comment: @trichetriche Yes. this is may she need when the data legth is more than 1000

Comment: @trichetriche If the data length is more than 1000, then only we may need to use setTimout() function for the large date binding

Comment: @trichetriche... can you please check out this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49493314/unable-to-display-the-selected-rows-from-mat-table-in-angular-2-using-angular-ma

Comment: @RameshRajendran... please checkout this link

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49493314/unable-to-display-the-selected-rows-from-mat-table-in-angular-2-using-angular-ma

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple after close of dialog to subscibe and call listing API

```
openDialog(requestId): void {
   //this.abc=requestId;
   const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DialogOverviewExampleDialog,  {
     disableClose: true,
     width: '400px',
     data: { name: this.name, animal: this.animal, sendtochild: requestId }
   });

   dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
     this.getUserList();
   });
}
```