# Unable to display the selected rows from mat-table in angular 2 using angular material

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material

I have implemented a simple table in angular 2 using angular material with select box.

As i select the desired rows and click on transfer selected rows, the rows are spliced and the spliced rows are being displayed in my console..

But I am unable to display them in my output window..

Please go through the link to access the [sample example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-app-material-h2lcps?file=app%2Faccount%2Faccount.component.ts)

I want to display the console output on my output screen .....can anybody please help me to implement this functionality....!

Below shown is my current output window...
[image]

Comment: First, ngFor expression for "selected rows" is kind of broken. Second, in the transfer method, you are splicing the original table source without keeping the transfered data copy. Hope this helps

Comment: yes i dont want to keep the copy .. so  i have spliced ... how can i display the console output on my screen..?

Comment: checkout this: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nwjqsj

Comment: @Vega... thanks a lot... its working fine ...but please can you tell me what is the role of pageEvent here...?

Comment: it's reminiscent of AM example code that I forked. you ignore and delete it

Comment: @Vega.... Hello  Vega.. I have one more query..... in the same example i have implemented deleting rows functionality... I am able to delete the selected rows from mat-table.. But I want to delete the transferred rows from the selected rows section

Comment: can you please access...https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-app-material-h2lcps?file=app%2Faccount%2Faccount.component.ts

Comment: can you please help to implement this functionality....

Comment: @Vega... hey can you please check out this question....https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49535102/deleting-selected-items-from-mat-list-not-working-in-angular-2-using-angular-mat