# Deleting selected items from mat-list not working in angular 2 using angular material

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have implemented a simple table in angular 2 using angular material ..Implemented two methods , first is **transferSelectedRows** which on selecting rows from table pushes the row data to Selected Rows section.

Second method is **removeSelectedRows** where on selecting the rows and clicking **Remove Selected Rows** button should delete the corresponding list items.But I am unable to delete the items from the **mat-selection-list**...

Can anybody please help me out ...!

please access my sample example here ..https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nwjqsj-au6ho8?file=index.html

### Below shown is the output of my sample angular 2 app.

[image]

Comment: @Safiyya... can you please check this out .....https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nwjqsj-au6ho8?file=app%2Faccount.component.ts

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nwjqsj-au6ho8?file=index.html... please check this

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nwjqsj-au6ho8?file=main.ts... i modified

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167734/discussion-between-heena-and-safiyya).

Comment: From what I can see, when you select items from the right column to delete them, your `this.selection.selected` is empty. That might be a good start for debugging your app.

Comment: I am not getting...!

Comment: in your `removeSelectedRows` function, try to `console.log(this.selection)` before it goes into the `forEach` to see if there is any `this.selection.selected` items in the array. Right now, when I select something from the list and click `remove items`, `this.selection.selected` is just an empty array. So your code will never enter the `forEach` method because the array is empty.

Comment: yes its showing me empty array ......

Comment: How should I assign the Selected rows to this array>.?

Comment: now I am getting the transferred rows array in my console after assigning the transferred rows..but I am getting the following error in my console..I have updated my output screen shot in my question

Comment: @filipbarak .. can you please help me now to resolve this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your `removeSelectedRows()` to filter the selected items in the table:

```
removeSelectedRows() {
    this.selection.selected.forEach(item => {
      this.selectedRows = this.selectedRows.filter(element => element !== item);
    });
  }
```

Comment: I am getting the following error in my terminal.Type 'any[ ]' is not assignable to type 'SelectionModel<Element>'

Comment: I'm on the phone right now so it's tricky to see it, but modifying how you declare `selectedRows` to `selectedRows: Element[] = []` (line 21) should fix the issue.

Comment: Sorry I misinterpreted your question, I had missed the checkboxes on the right. Let me re-elaborate my answer

Comment: @Heena Have yo got solution?

Comment: @RameshRajendran ... Hello Sir ,,,, Check this please ...https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49609355/transferring-rows-from-one-table-to-another-in-angular-2-using-angular-material