# Implemented a fixed header but the content is scrolling over the header

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-flex-layout

I am working with Angular 2 app using angular material and angular flex layout.I have created in my application a **login form** and **a header** which is only visible after login in my home page.

In my app.component.html I have added my header and applied the below style to get it fixed while scrolling.

```
<div style="margin-bottom:5px;
   top: 0;
    position: sticky;
    z-index: 1;
    background-color: inherit;">
```

In my home page I have added a **mat-toolbar** component,**mat-card** component and **mat-sidenav** component.

After logging in the app, when I scroll the homepage content is overlapping my fixed header and my header is getting covered with the home page content.

Please access my sample app [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-flex-sticky-header?file=app/app.component.html)

Can anybody please help me in proper implementation of my fixed header?

Comment: link does not work

Comment: Try setting position: relative; to the wrapper of your content

Comment: @Luckyfella... no its not working for me... its even scrolling the header

Comment: Äh, sorry: just saw your header need position: fixed; not sticky. Then it should work

Comment: @Luckyfella... no... now my header isn't visible in my home page

Comment: @ashfaq.p... it is availabel... can you please check it out

Comment: You got it or not? your sample link does not work for me :(

Comment: i didnt get it solved yet...

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-flex-sticky-header?file=app/app.component.html... please check this out

Comment: @Heena Still i can only see `Import error, can't find files:` error on  there

Comment: :-( but i am able to open it ... please give me 2 min

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-flex-sticky-header-9ya8tj... is this accessible..?

Comment: @Heena I can access the link. But I am unable to run it  because it throwing `Import error, can't find files:
src/index.html
src/main.ts`error

Comment: hmm.. i will check it again

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169083/discussion-between-ramesh-rajendran-and-heena).

Answer (score 0):

Increase your z-index to the following:

```
z-index: 998;
```

Answer (score -1):

Try something like this

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <header>Fixed header</header>
    <main> 
      <div *ngFor="let item of items"> Content </div>
    </main>
  `,
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  items = new Array(100)
}
```

**app.component.css**

```
header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 56px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: tomato;
}

main {
  margin-top: 56px;
  background-color: aliceblue;
}
```

With angular material you need to put `margin-top` on the `mat-sidenav-content` selector.

[Live demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8chmhl)

Comment: The content is overlapping header while scrolling. The margin-top helps only when window y is 0 I guess.